# How do I swap ani and dnis values around if direction is 0? If direction is 1 it should be left unchanged

Tags: xslt-1.0

How do I swap ani and dnis values around if direction is 0? If direction is 1 it should be left unchanged.

I have tried with a if command but can get it to work. I hope samebody have a solution for this little issue :)

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
        <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
            <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />
            <xsl:template match="/">
                <Call xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
                    <Data>
                        <time_offset>
                            <xsl:number value="0"/>
                        </time_offset>
                        <audio>
                            <audio_segement>
                                <channel_id>0</channel_id>
                                <recording_order>1</recording_order>
                                <audio_url>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="callinfo/location"/>
                                </audio_url>
                                <xsl:apply-templates select="callinfo/startdate"/>
                                <xsl:apply-templates select="StartTime"/>
                                                        <Duration>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="callinfo/duration"/>
                                </Duration>
                            </audio_segement>
                        </audio>
                        <direction>
                            <xsl:value-of select="callinfo/direction"/>
                        </direction>
                        <ani>
                            <xsl:value-of select="callinfo/local"/>
                        </ani>
                        <dnis>
                            <xsl:value-of select="callinfo/remote"/>
                        </dnis>
                        <unique_identifier>
                            <xsl:value-of select="callinfo/startdate"/>
                        </unique_identifier>
                                        <pbx_login_id>
                                        <xsl:value-of select="callinfo/local"/>
                                        </pbx_login_id>
                                        <switch_name>Mobile Data Source</switch_name>
                    </Data>
                </Call>
            </xsl:template>
            <xsl:template match="callinfo/startdate">
                <StartTime>
                <xsl:variable name="StartTime">
                    <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring-before(., ' '), 'T', substring-after(., ' '))"/>
                </xsl:variable>
                <xsl:variable name="startTimeSize" select = "string-length(.)"/>
                <xsl:if test="$startTimeSize = 19">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$StartTime"/>.00+00:00
                </xsl:if>
                <xsl:if test="$startTimeSize = 33">
                    <xsl:value-of select="substring($StartTime,0,24)"/>
                    <xsl:value-of select="substring($StartTime,28,7)"/>
                </xsl:if>
                <xsl:if test="$startTimeSize != 33 and $startTimeSize != 19">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$StartTime"/>
                </xsl:if>       
            </StartTime>
        </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What exactly does "swap around" mean in this context?

Comment: I just want ani and dnis to change places if direction is 0 and if direction is 1 it should be unchanged.

Comment: maybe an input XML will help. Please post this also.

Answer (score 0):

I am still not sure I understand this. If you just want to change the **order** in which the elements appear in the output document, without changing their contents, change this part:

```
<ani>
    <xsl:value-of select="callinfo/local"/>
</ani>
<dnis>
    <xsl:value-of select="callinfo/remote"/>
</dnis>
```

to:

```
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="callinfo/direction=1">
        <ani><xsl:value-of select="callinfo/local"/></ani>
        <dnis><xsl:value-of select="callinfo/remote"/></dnis>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
        <dnis><xsl:value-of select="callinfo/remote"/></dnis>
        <ani><xsl:value-of select="callinfo/local"/></ani>
    </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

Note that in a well-designed XML, the order of siblings should not matter - that's what element names are there for.